# Typing effect with Javascript - can't get it to simulate an error in typing

Tags: javascript

I stripped out everything and placed it in one HTML file so it's easier to test just this part.

The goal here is for it to first type **`Wx`** then remove the **`x`** wait for a **second**, then type **`elcome`**.

The code now produces **Wlcome**, I tried many things but **can't** get it to type the `**Welcome**` with the first `e`.

Please help

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#typing-area');

let textToType = 'Welcome';
const delayTime = 1000;


const typingSpeed = 100;
let currentIndex = 0;

function typeLetter() {
  const currentText = element.innerHTML;

  if (currentIndex === 1) {
    element.innerHTML += 'x';
    setTimeout(removeX, 1000);
  } else {

    element.innerHTML = currentText + textToType[currentIndex];

    currentIndex++;

    if (currentIndex < textToType.length) {
      setTimeout(typeLetter, typingSpeed);
    }
  }
}


function removeX() {
  const currentText = element.innerHTML;
  element.innerHTML = currentText.slice(0, -1);
  currentIndex = 2;
  setTimeout(typeLetter, typingSpeed);
}


setTimeout(typeLetter, 500);
```

```css
#typing-area::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.1em;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Typing Example</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="typing-area"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are skipping the `e`, by going from `currentIndex` 0 directly to 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not modify your `currentIndex (= 2)`, just add flag, that you already printed error out, so your next iteration continues as normal text:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#typing-area');

let textToType = 'Welcome';
const delayTime = 1000;


const typingSpeed = 100;
let currentIndex = 0;
let hasErrorTyped = false;

function typeLetter() {
  const currentText = element.innerHTML;

  if (currentIndex === 1 && !hasErrorTyped) {
    element.innerHTML += 'x';
    setTimeout(removeX, 1000);
    hasErrorTyped = true;
  } else {

    element.innerHTML = currentText + textToType[currentIndex];

    currentIndex++;

    if (currentIndex < textToType.length) {
      setTimeout(typeLetter, typingSpeed);
    }
  }
}


function removeX() {
  const currentText = element.innerHTML;
  element.innerHTML = currentText.slice(0, -1);
  setTimeout(typeLetter, typingSpeed);
}


setTimeout(typeLetter, 500);
```

```css
#typing-area::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.1em;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Typing Example</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="typing-area"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You beat me by 3 mins.

Comment: *Alternatively* add the `e` when you remove the `x`, but you'd need a small amount of refactoring to stop DRY

Answer (score 2):

I kind of made your code more clear using promises

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#typing-area');

const typingSpeed = 100;

type()

async function type() {
  await wait(500)
  await typeLetters('Wx')
  await wait(1000)
  await removeLetters(1)
  await typeLetters('elcome')
}

function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function typeLetters(letters) {
  for (const char of letters) {
    element.textContent += char
    await wait(typingSpeed)
  }
}

async function removeLetters(count) {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
    element.textContent = element.textContent.slice(0, -1)
    await wait(typingSpeed)
  }
}
```

```css
#typing-area::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.1em;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Typing Example</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="typing-area"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are simply checking if the `currentIndex === 1` every time. So the first run through it replaces the `e` with an `x`, and it would just do that every time.  Your solution was to manually force the index to `2`, which is why the letter is skipped over.  Remember, indexes begin at `0`!

```
0 - W
1 - e
2 - l
3 - c
5 - o
6 - m
7 - e
```

So when you manually force the index to be `2`, that's the letter right after the first `e`, so it was skipped over.

---

So, what I've done below is just added a bit of "state tracking" with a `hasTypedError` boolean so that the branch of code that types the `x` only runs that first time.  I also moved your `currentIndex++` to be outside of the `if` statement so that it can increment for both branches, and I fixed the manual index reset in the `removeX` function to reset to the correct index now.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#typing-area');

let textToType = 'Welcome';
const delayTime = 1000;

const typingSpeed = 100;
let currentIndex = 0;
let hasTypedError = false;

function typeLetter() {
  const currentText = element.innerHTML;

  if (currentIndex === 1 && !hasTypedError) {
    element.innerHTML += 'x';
    hasTypedError = true;
    setTimeout(removeX, 1000);
  } else {

    element.innerHTML = currentText + textToType[currentIndex];

    if (currentIndex < textToType.length - 1 ) {
      setTimeout(typeLetter, typingSpeed);
    }
  }
  currentIndex++;
  
  console.log('type', currentIndex, element.innerHTML)
}


function removeX() {
  const currentText = element.innerHTML;
  element.innerHTML = currentText.slice(0, -1);
  currentIndex = 1
  setTimeout(typeLetter, typingSpeed);
  
  console.log('remove', currentIndex, element.innerHTML)
}

//Start it all off
setTimeout(typeLetter, 500);
```

```css
#typing-area::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.1em;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Typing Example</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="typing-area"></div>

</body>

</html>
```